# Can a 40amp breaker be used safely and without issue with a 40amp device on 6AWG wire?

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel

We are installing a Cooktop that calls for a 40amp circuit. I was given 6AWG wire (instead of the 8AWG wire I asked for) by mistake. The electrician saw the 6AWG wire (that I had already run) and used a 50amp breaker. The Cooktop installer requires that the breaker be 40amp. My electrician was concerned that using the larger 6AWG wire would lower the resistance therefore affecting the amps; he cited Ohm's law. He has refused to change the breaker from 50amps to 40amps for fear of damaging something or affecting safety. I thought the amp requirement was dictated by the device (it asks for 40amps) and the 40amp breaker would ensure that 40amps is all that it would get. Does anyone know of any dangers/issues if using a smaller breaker with 6AWG wire?

Comment: Electrically there is no issue. Ohm's law has nothing to do with it. The cable is not the resistive part of the circuit. For the code part, though, see answers.

Comment: Clearly the "electrician" doesn't understand what he's talking about.  Certainly using 6 AWG vs. 8 AWG will provide lower resistance IN THE WIRING which ends up generating less heat in your walls.  But that's NOT going to impact how much current the cooktop draws significantly.  Putting a 40A breaker would be fine here since it's LOWER than the wire's capacity.

Comment: Your electrician is wrong. He probably understands nothing about what he's doing, rather he just pattern matches: This wire = this breaker, and isn't able to actually think about it. Fire him, or monitor him closely.

Comment: I absolutely would **not** use this "electrician" anymore. If his understanding is this lacking for something so simple, imagine how much understanding he could lack in safety-critical areas..

Comment: Are you in the USA?  Although the physics does not change by location the wiring regulations do.

Comment: I am curious as to where you found this "electrician" who appears to have numerous false *elementary* beliefs about electricity. Is this electrician actually licensed?

Comment: Just possibly it is not correct wiring code. Though the reasoning of your electrician does not explain why. Perhaps along the lines of 'a person ought to expect that a circuit with 6AWG wiring is fused at 50A' .

Comment: I imagine the electrician very possibly knows the wire is fine, and is bluffing by citing a safety issue he thinks you won't understand - that way he doesn't have to change the breaker out (probably for free). Depending on when/where the discussion was had, he would have to go acquire / provide a different (cheaper) breaker, drive out to the site again, remove the breaker, and install the new one without getting paid any more. Much easier to lie to a small-time customer he's not expecting much business out of anyways, and move on to the next job.

Comment: If the cooktop has some electronics in it - not just electric elements, "dumb" switches, and a mechanical timer - then the breaker may not actually protect the device.  There's an old joke among electronic engineers that transistors were invented to protect fuses, because that's usually how it goes.

Comment: So the circuit protection can really be thought of as only protecting the wire that feeds the device, not the device itself.  At that point, you can upsize the wire all you want and be perfectly okay...as long as you can still make a connection.

Comment: It is fairly common to use a thicker (smaller numbered) wire than "normal" when the cable run exceeds a given distance such that the resistance of the smaller wire would cause too much voltage drop.

Comment: 40amp device on a 40amp circuit.  The breaker would trip all the time.  This is a bad question.  -1

Comment: @danny117 where are you getting that from? Nowhere in the question does it state that the appliance draws 40 amps.

Comment: @Steve, when you state "[the device] asks for 40 amps", does its documentation and labeling state that a) *only* a 40 amp breaker should be used, no greater, b) that the device is rated at 40 amps @ 240v power consumption, or c) the circuit should be capable of at least 40 amps?  Is this cooktop plug-in or hard wired?

Comment: As stated by many others, I question this electrician's understanding of basic electric theory or his motive for his statement.  Using larger wire will not cause the device to draw more current than is needed. Wiring a flashlight with #0 wire won't cause it to draw 100+ amps. Likewise, using 6 AWG wire won't cause the cooktop to draw more than 40 amps, it would only allow the wires to carry more without creating a hazard due to overheating the wiring. I see the 50A breaker on 6AWG wire as an upgrade over the minimum.

Comment: What happens if about 5 years later a new DIY owner wants to replace the range, sees the 6 gauge wire and thinks, "sweet I can get a 50A model" but never notices/considers or upgrades the 40A breaker?

Comment: a) Not likely - they're going to see the breaker when they turn it off to work on things, if nothing else, plus knowing wire sizes and *not* at least looking at the breaker makes no sense; b) if they actually did that and got nuisance trips, they'd figure out pretty quickly that the breaker should be replaced with the correct size. The problem is the opposite - don't look at the wire size and simply swap the breaker (when the wire can't actually handle the larger breaker) - this is the one time that won't be a problem.

Answer (score 45):

Your "electrician" is not one of the brighter bulbs in the pack.

The 40A is to protect the wiring and the device.

If the wiring is AT LEAST 8Ga then it's adequate to protect the wiring. It also protects 6Ga, (or 500 MCM for that matter) just fine, and it properly protects the device at the end of the wire just fine.

"Ohms law" has squat to do with this. You could have a cooktop located 3 feet from the breaker panel and connected with 8 Ga or one located 100 feet from the panel and connected with 6 Ga - the 8 Ga would have (much, about 20 times) lower resistance, because of the wire length. Upsizing wire for longer runs on heavy circuits is actually quite normal. As stated, not a particularly knowledgeable electrician you have there.

Comment: But I'm sure he had no problem producing a bill for his "excellent" services.

Comment: I'd say your description of the electrician is a massive understatement. If he fails to grasp the very basics of the safety principles, he's worse than useless. Who knows how many oversized breakers he's installed during his career. Most of those poor homeowners would be better off and safer if they just did it themselves.

Comment: He charged by the hour and actually didn't count the hour he was waiting for me to go get the 50amp breaker. He had helped us previously and his rates are decent. However, I think he may need some more time to mature on the theory vs reality aspects. He saw 6AWG and knew that normally matched up with 50amps. Based on his knowledge, straying from that could cause unknown issues.

Comment: Good luck getting 500MCM wire to fit into the terminals of a 40A breaker, though!

Comment: I would have phrased this as "Do not let your "electrician" touch anything electrical in your house again.  He is criminally negligent."

Comment: @SteveSensabaugh: Upsizing wire is at least somewhat common, though. It's not some obscure edge-case that never comes up in the real world.  In fact I'd bet it's something you're tested on to get your license.

Comment: I don't think the electrician did anything wrong. 50A is an eminently reasonable choice for a 6AWG range circuit.  The sockets are 50A (no such thing as a 40A socket) and *many* 40A ranges are dual-listed for 40A or 50A breakers.  I would have done the same.

Comment: 40amp device 40 amp circuit = circuit trips

Answer (score 29):

The breaker needs to be sized to protect the **wire** and the **device**.

#### Wire

Larger wire (which is a lower # due to the way wire sizes are named) can use a larger breaker. But a smaller breaker is always **safe**. 55A is the largest breaker you can normally use for 6 AWG copper. 40A is the largest breaker you can normally use for 8 AWG copper. But you can always use a smaller breaker - it will be 100% safe. That includes the very typical 50A (instead of 55A) for 6 AWG. But it can include lots of different things. For example, a 30A breaker on 8 AWG wire, a 15A breaker with 12 AWG wire (which can also use a 20A breaker), etc. You could even use a 15A breaker on 6 AWG wire - strange but nothing unsafe about it.

#### Device

The device needs to be protected by an appropriate size breaker which is determined by the design of the device and is part of the UL (or equivalent) listing for the device. So if the cooktop calls for a 40A breaker then you **must** use a 40A breaker. You can't use a smaller breaker (probably safe, but you would get frequent nuisance trips which are inconvenient at best and lead to unsafe operation at worst if you (or a future owner) ends up "fixing" it later in an unsafe manner). And you can't use a larger breaker because the device is not rated for that - i.e., it expects to have the protection provided by a 40A breaker in order to handle any faults in a safe manner.

It is possible to have multiple valid breaker sizes. For example, a circuit consisting of 12 AWG wire and 15A duplex receptacles can use a 15A breaker (perfect match for the individual receptacles) or 20A breaker - OK because of the wire size (15A would only need 14 AWG) and a special exception for 20A circuits that allows for multiple 15A receptacles instead of 1-or-more 20A receptacles, and the 15A receptacles are designed to allow 20A passing through. Any normal plug-in 15A device can use a 20A receptacle. But that is not necessarily the case for 40A vs. 50A - and unless the cooktop instructions actually say it is OK to do so, you need to stick with 40A, *even if the wire can handle 50A*.

Comment: Although technically true you can use 15A breaker on the 6AWG, the breaker may not be designed for a wire of that thickness, so you may actually have problems installing it properly.

Comment: @Nelson I realize that. I used 15A with 6 AWG as an extreme example.

Comment: This answer needs more upvotes for getting the most important point - if the appliance calls for a 40A breaker, not a 40A or higher breaker, its internal wiring may be unsafe if allowed to carry current greater than 40A under fault conditions. You absolutely need to put the 40A breaker back and fire (and ideally report) this incompetent electrician.

Comment: This case may be from a state that doesn’t require licenses, yes they are out there, as  @manassehkatz stated it would be just fine to use #6 on a small circuit, you would pigtail to the max size the breaker will allow, this is done for voltage drop all the time+.

Answer (score 24):

### You're always allowed to upsize wire

What you have there is a 40A circuit, because it is breakered 40A per instructions.

On a 40A circuit you are allowed to use any cable 8 AWG or larger.

It's that simple.

6 AWG is larger than 8 AWG, so you are ducky-doo with the #6. **Good call**, since some better stoves/ranges want 50A or even 60A, and #6 is good for all that.

The only speedbump with the "any size or larger" is a *very much larger* wire may not physically fit on the breaker or panel lugs.  In that case you need to simply pigtail to an intermediate size or metallurgy.  For instance if you wisely chose 4 AWG Aluminum for your 400' long-run 30A dryer circuit, neither the 30A breaker nor socket will accept #4 nor aluminum.  So you use Al-rated Polaris connectors to pigtail to #10 Cu, which will fit without trouble. #10Cu is good on a 30A circuit.

As for the electrician's "mistake" I don't see the problem. If he wasn't aware of the range specs, he made absolutely correct assumptions based on facts at hand.  Many 40A ranges are dual-listed for 40 or 50A breakers, and both use the same socket. If wrong, it's a $9 change.  No big.

Comment: With just the small caveat of 'but the wire has to fit the terminals of the breaker and device properly'. A 15 A breaker might not accept a 6 GA wire properly. I know that you know this, and that circuit breakers are labeled appropriately, but it's worth pointing out for a DIY site.

Comment: @Adonalsium good point, edited.

Comment: And downsize the breaker.

Comment: plan for the future.  Someday someone will plug in a space heater.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue (or would have had 7 years ago after i bought my fixer upper by the lake and discovered that only one electrician lived in this area that had not yet become part of metro Charleston, SC) with wiring for which I'd paid $500 that I now see amounted to robbery, which by God's grace didn't end up as a 1,900 square foot mound of embers. The 49-year stick-built rambler I bought had been abandoned for three years following a caustic divorce between two narcissists comprising a residential contractor/drug dealer and his grossly drug addicted wife. (The ex-husband acquired the home nextdoor, and thinks I'm living in his house despite the deed recording otherwise.
It's been exhaustive living nextdoor to a OCD-driven bully who's evil orchestrations included compromising every handyman I hired to sabotage whatever I'd paid them to fix, install or upgrade. This included wiring my new stove and wall oven, and another, a master electrician and fraudulently licensed contractor, to finish my garage creating two rooms and a laundry closet. He'd installed my metal roof (atop the old shingles and two busted joists, all without an inch of flashing). After i paid him $18k plus as much for materials in 2014, he immediately bought a pile of cocaine, then later boasted in a local bar that he'd wired my house to burn. I provide this background to help explain some of the curios comments, questions and whatever offered 2-cent suggestions i may have. Juxtapose, after pulling my rusted out GE cooktop I'd bought to replace a working old cooktop (the only thing wrong with it was that awful '70s mustard color). The electrician i hired was the neighborhood gossip who relished defaming me with flatly fabricated tales about me all while i was paying him four times what anyone paid anybody for work here. Based on my plumber's training, the electrician may have acquired his skills in prison. He had a gift for code-breaking workarounds. I recall hearing him "hmm," as he began installing my new 40 amp oven next to my new drop in stove. He used the existing original fat sheathed black cable that was either 4 or 6 awg stranded. He created a junction box in which he twisted and taped together the two appliance line sets to the twisted heavy gauge copper stranded cables from a 60-amp breaker. So, somehow he connected super thick copper cables to bundles of 10 awg stranded aluminum wire sets from the two appliances in a 5" metal junction box and everything worked just fine... Until I over-boiled peanuts in salt water a few too many times that accelerated rusting of the cheap GE stove top. After my life here prompted me to move an hour away, crack-addicted burglar became a squatter of my lake house who must have turned my place into a cat house.literally, because a feral tomcat sprayed my stove as evidenced by the distinctive pungent cat spray stench when i tried to cook something. Cat urine also is highly acidic, corrosive, which was worse than overboiling peanuts in salt water based on the accelerated rust that rendered an otherwise useful stovetop totally corroded from elusive, adherent cat spray and resulting toxic plume. So disgusted, I pulled out the whole thing, stovetop and underlying drip pan.
This revealed sections of swollen pressed wood beneath the 70s yellow formica countertop, which I trimmed away. Roughly 5" below the counter was the 5" metal junction box the electrician set when he installed my stove and new wall oven. Upon uncovering that revealed thickly twisted copper and black electrical tape and two metal conduits, a 1" cable leading to the oven, a 3/4" metal conduit leading to the stove and the 3/4" black-sleeved cable fished under the house via crawlspace from the 60-amp breaker in the Square D circuit panel ~18' away in the wall of the finished garage behind the den and fireplace. Since the stove is gone, I wondered if that junction box could be used to power a 20-amp outlet for my two new pluggable countertop stoves. One is conduction and the other is a glass top electric stove unit for ferrous cookware. I also plan to install a two-eye LPG fueled cooktop (I'd prefer a single eye one, but they all look like cheap little camp stoves). Each of my electric units are rated 1800 watt capacity, and neither would be on max heat simultaneously. Either way, I wondered why two 20 amp outlets couldn't be fashioned to work off of what had also powered a four-eye drop-in stovetop. Yet, my assumption was flawed, and I've been advised to install dedicated 20-amp circuits for each single burner. Problem remains what to do with the heavy duty cable, a 60 amp breaker on the single wall oven that was meant for a 40 amp breaker. The reminder of why God gave us electricians was indicated by my decision to cap the cables and leave the junction to serve the stove. It was because I misjudged that the red coated wire as neutral so that after i capped the stove's white and red cables together, and then bound together the two fat service black wires and the oven's black (hot) lines, the 60 amp breaker seemed to moan when the breaker i hit also snap-crackle-popped loudly back idf when i flipped it on. As I paused, retreating from my kitchen and re-imagined cooktop project, flashbacks and an ah-ha moment emerged when i realized that the red wire was hot not neutral, so binding a hot to a neutral is forbidden. I'm now left with the questions: Are all of the hot lines, black and the red, supposed to be twisted together, or one of the fat black cables bound to the 10 awg hot lines separately, the two black service cables separately bound to the thinner appliance hot lines so at least i could securely and more neatly cap each of the two bound sets? The effect would be the same, right? And what do i do with the straggling white line from the oven? Just cap it? Finally, does that thick twisted mass of copper ground wires pose a threat to the unwitting soul who'd get a jolt from touching it by extending a long metal utensil to the metal box grounded by a mass of ground copper? Ah, the consequences of moving out of the city to the country where the slow pace is backward mentality by provincial local opposed to progress and anyone new.

Comment: Hello, please edit and remove the rant.  Keep it short and to the point.  This site does not run like a forum.

Answer (score -5):

The breaker now matches the wire rating (so you are protected against wall fires from overheating wires) and exceeds the cooktop rating (so it will not trigger accidentally).  You are fine, but you'd have been fine with a 40A breaker as well.  You state that the cooktop calls for a 40A breaker but that just means that the breaker (and wire) should be able to deliver at least 40A.  The makers of the cooktop cannot delegate operating security to the wire breaker.  Arguably without additional circuitry it would be a bad idea to mount the cooktop on a 5000A rail since it might melt into slag in case of a shortcircuit.  The difference between 50A and 40A for the fault modes to be expected, however, are negligible.  There just isn't a failure mode where the cooktop would continually draw, say, 48A through its internal wiring.

Unless, of course, some terminals have been mixed up and parts are running between different phases rather than between phase and ground, leading to a consistent too high load but not a short circuit.  While the overall competence of your electrician does not seem overwhelming, his insistence on sticking with what he knows makes that unlikely.  If you find that some of your plates heat water significantly faster than expected, you probably should have that double-checked.

Comment: Just read what you said "There isn't a failure mode" + "Unless, of course..." You can't have it both ways.

Answer (score -9):

You are lucky you got a 50amp circuit for your commercial kitchen.  Enjoy.  You can also plug a waffle iron in at the same time!  Think of this as an upgrade.

OP is wrong electrician is correct using a 50amp circuit.  It won't damage anything.n

Edit 20220314 ahh you lost in court by now but the down votes are really hurting the question.  The correct answer was the license electrician you got an upgrade for free they will not come back if they did come back be very afraid. Hahahahahahahaha sass.

thanks continued down votes I know what is right and wrong.

you can charge a Tesla on 6awg circuit. You could charge an ev on your kitchen plugs how safe is that. Paid for a 40 got a 50 that's really a bonus.

I have sperated lines in my kitchen dishwasher a separate line refrigerator a separate line counter plugs a separate line.  Guess what kids there all different amperages and wire sizes.  I know the dishwasher is spec because I installed the dishwasher after inspection of the circuit nice big wire direct to box is good.

Happy pie day

Comment: Absolutely wrong: (a) You can't plug a waffle iron (or other 120V 15A/20A appliance) into a 240V 40A/50A circuit; (b) a 40A/50A circuit isn't a duplex receptacle anyway; (c) it isn't a commercial kitchen; (d) we don't **know** if it "won't damage anything" without knowing the specs for the cooktop.

Comment: Two phase still an upgrade op was wrong for asking really childish I have 20 amp service to every plug in my kitchen has it damaged my 3amp coffee pot no and it never will.  50 amp is upgrade.  You manassethkalf are a Hazzard to all things electric.

Comment: Will a 2amp phone charger die on a 10amp plug no.  Becareful amps will kill you.  Op got really nice upgrade.

Comment: UL (and similar listing of products based on proper design and testing) includes certification of what size circuit a device can use. A 2amp phone charger (actually 2A @ 5V = small fraction of 1A @ 120V, but irrelevant) is **designed** so that it will function properly on a 15A or 20A circuit, such that if it fails it will (hopefully) fail in a way that the breaker will trip. It **can** be designed to work fine on a 50A circuit too, but the concern is whether it could have a failure mode at 30A or 40A such that the device would melt/catch fire without the breaker tripping. The OPs question...

Comment: is a real one. Many cooktops, ovens, etc. are designed for 40A **or** 50A circuit, but if they are designed/tested/listed **only for 40A** then if there is a fire because of a failure on a 50A circuit **then insurance may deny the claim** due to improper use/installation. These are **real** issues.

Comment: danny117, no offense but you clearly have no idea what you're talking about.  You can upgrade your house service from (say) 100 amp to 200 amp, and you could even upgrade a kitchen circuit from 15 amp to 20 amp, but you cannot "upgrade" a kitchen circuit from 20 amp to 50 amp. 50 amp circuits can _only_ be used by large appliances like ranges (stoves) and dryers.  You couldn't plug a coffee maker into it if you tried, the outlets are completely different.

Comment: @danny117 your 3 amp device is rated for a 15 amp circuit, the draw of the device has little to do with the rating. However there is a code limit, a device cannot be connected to a circuit that is more than 150% of its listing . to make it simple if the plug in prongs are parallel its listed for a 15 amp circuit but can be plugged into a 20 amp branch circuit even if it only draws 100ma. Manassehkatz is correct. With -7 you think you would get a clue.

Comment: @Ed Beal, you stated that per code "a device cannot be connected to a circuit that is more than 150% of its listing."  To clarify, is this 150% of its listed voltage, current draw, or what?  Does this only apply to hard wired items, or plug-in and socketed (e.g. light bulbs) as well?  I'm not a licensed master electrician but would like to understand the actual code requirements; can you cite the applicable code version and section for our education?

Comment: Ampacity is the key here , a device will only draw the amount of current it requires and the circuit breakers are there to prevent to much current if there is a fault. A good example of this is a light bulb hooked up to a 20 amp circuit a 100w bulb will draw .83 amps (P/E=I) there is 20 amps available at 120v , if you were to put a 120v lightbulb in a 240v circuit it would emit a very bright flash and burn out because of the wrong voltage. I have seen internal wires of the bulb shorted causing the breaker to trip the breaker is protecting the wiring from over current damage. NEC 422.11.E.3

Comment: Its never going to fail so this is a non issue.  OP did get a nice upgrade lower gauge wires higher amp circuit no fires in the wiring.  Notice how there is nothing from the manufacture of the cook top here either... OP doesn't get a refund if that is what there looking for.  Electrician doesn't have to come back either.  I know I would never do business with the OP.  @ed yah you can apply ohms law so you know how warm stove wires get and that it is a nice upgrade.

Comment: Boomers  six plugs on circuit all six using 8 amps..  48amps.  What Guage wire when you know current in the supply wires will be 48amps.   Your house with cheap wire burned to the ground.  My house is serving waffles 6 running and that's 4 more than the breakfast buffet has.  That's also why you don't see more than two at the motel 6awg breakfast bar.